# Best way to add a library web part to an page layout

Tags: web-part, page-layout, custom

I'm creating SPWebs based on WebTemplates, which each one have is own, for the welcome page, have modules for the pagelayout and default.aspx page.

At this point I'm using a PublishingLayoutPage and showing some metadata fields of the page created from this page layout as well with a webpart zone.

But now I need to embedded in the same default.aspx the docLib view web part of a specific docLib of that SPWeb (docLib will always have a diff. internal name)

What is the most easy and correct approach for initialize this custom webPart?

I've checked this [link](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-default-web-parts-ab7aec72), but I think that is not the ideal approach for what I want. I think that what I need is less complex.

ideas?

Comment: So you can't add a webpart based on something like "Shared Documents"?

Comment: yes, but the docLIb with a custom internal name (url name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reach this first concept solution, probably not the best one but its enough for now.

```
public static void AddListViewWebPart(SPWeb oWeb, SPFile oFile, SPList oSPList, string webPartTitle, string webPartZone)
{
    bool state = oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    //Create the object SPLimitedWebPart Manager
    SPLimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = oFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

    //Create the object of ListViewer webpart
    var oListViewWP = new ListViewWebPart
                          {
                              ChromeType = PartChromeType.TitleOnly,
                              Title = webPartTitle,
                              ListName = oSPList.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
                          };

    //Define the zone in which webparts need to be added
    limitedWebPartManager.AddWebPart(oListViewWP, webPartZone, 1);
    oWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = state;
}
```

Thanks for your help Stefano.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using onet.xml in your SiteDefinition you can use the following code:

```
<Module Name="DefaultBlank0" Url="$Resources:osrvcore,List_Pages_UrlName;" Path="">
  <File Path="default.aspx" Url="default.aspx" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
    <Property Name="Title" Value="Intranet" />
    <Property Name="ContentType" Value="$Resources:cmscore,contenttype_welcomepage_name;" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageLayout" Value="~SiteCollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MySiteListingLayout.aspx, Home Page" />
    <Property Name="PublishingPageContent" Value="Hi all" />
    <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="MainTopListing" WebPartOrder="0">
      <![CDATA[
        <webParts>
          <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
            <metaData>
              <type name="YourAssembly.WebParts.common.NewsWebPart.NewsWebPart, YourAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=37b39a266ae2abb5" />
              <importErrorMessage>Error importing the Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
            </metaData>
            <data>
              <properties>
                <property name="Title" type="string">News Web Part</property>
              </properties>
            </data>
          </webPart>
        </webParts>
      ]]>
    </AllUsersWebPart>
```

Comment: but like that, I'm just creating the webpart zone, right? I need to add a docLib web part view. (sorry the basic doubt)

Comment: You prepare the pagelayout with WebPartZone and then in sitedefinition (Onet.xml) can enter the code you've written, or under provisioning through a eventreceiver you can hook the webpart in the WebPartZone objectmodel

Comment: using this example: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Adding-default-web-parts-ab7aec72
for add the WP to the default page? that's it?

Answer (score 1):

For example i use this code:

```
PublishingPage publicProfilePage = sps.AddPublishingPage("Public.aspx", layout);

                var wpm = publicProfilePage.ListItem.File.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
```

WebPartsHelper.AddWebPart(wpm, "ProfileWebPart", "MainLeftColumn", 0);

and the static method AddWebPart:

public static void AddWebPart(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager, WebPartParam webPart, string zoneId, int zoneIndex)
        {
            XDocument webPartXmlSettings = GetWebPartFile(wpManager, webPart.WebPartName);
            if (webPartXmlSettings != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    XmlReader xtr = webPartXmlSettings.CreateReader();
                    var errorMsg = string.Empty;
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart newWebPart = wpManager.ImportWebPart(xtr, out errorMsg);

```
                // Web part values initialization.
                object values = webPart.WebPartValues;
                if (values != null)
                {
                    Type webPartType = newWebPart.GetType();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo p in values.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        PropertyInfo wpProperty = webPartType.GetProperty(p.Name);
                        if (wpProperty != null)
                        {
                            wpProperty.SetValue(newWebPart, p.GetValue(values, null), null);
                        }
                    }
                }

                newWebPart.ChromeType = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PartChromeType.None;
                wpManager.AddWebPart(newWebPart, zoneId, zoneIndex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace(0,
                    new SPDiagnosticsCategory("WebPartsHelper.AddWebPart() Error", TraceSeverity.Medium, EventSeverity.Error),
                    TraceSeverity.Unexpected, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```